# Change theme of TextView etc in a Dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

So i used android holo theme generator but and applied it successfully,for textviews etc but i don't know how to apply that theme into the dialog ?
Please can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried using the following constructor 'Dialog(Context context, int theme)'

Comment: hi,thank you for telling me this and making my life so simple :D
but again i have one more question...i haven't used themes like this,so how can i ?
I mean Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this,R.theme.something) 

or is it something else?
write your comment as an answer and i will accept it :D

Comment: okay got it,
R.style.aaptheme

Comment: but it didn't work lol

Comment: Can you put your theme code here?

Comment: the themes are working now but i have got a strange problem now...i don't see the background activity anymore

Comment: You can actually create a separate xml layout for your dialog and inflate it - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: You are probably setting some other properties as well in your theme which causes this. Can you paste the xml for the theme?

Comment: yea got it working,i was using a flag dim behind,which wasn't working earlier ,but after i added the style it started working and i couldn't figure out what's wrong...thank you by the way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the following constructor 'Dialog(Context context, int theme)'

Comment: You are probably setting some other properties as well in your theme which causes this. Can you paste the xml for the theme?